# Change navigationBar appearance

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, appearance

My application flow: `AViewController -> BViewController -> CViewController` (via navigationController). `AViewController` and `CViewController` looks the same, only `BViewController` looks different.

I did it this way:

```
/// AppDelegate (should be 'super' settings)
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABCNavigationController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:theImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

/// BViewController (should apply ONLY to BViewController)
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:BImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The problem is that in `CViewController` i see the image i loaded in `BViewController` not in `appDelegate`. How to restore it to appDelegate settings?

I should underline that backgroundImage is one of many elements that i setup, gave it here as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CViewController` try setting the navbar's background image to `nil` in `viewWillAppear`, cause it reamains set by your `BViewController`.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It makes backgroundImage disappear at all, it doesn't load the one from appDelegate, but deletes the one from BViewController (and do not restore appDelegate one).

Comment: I see. I thought you hag the default navbar in all of the screens, except the B VC. Then simply set that background image in the C VC you have in the AppDelegate.

Comment: I gave full explanation and example where it was shown that i have different image set in A and C. Anyway thanks for visiting. Do you have any idea now how to fix it?

Comment: You said "AViewController and CViewController looks the same, only BViewController looks different." Well then i would erase that line from app delegate, and set the background of the navbar in each `ViewController`'s `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: But also wrote that i want to restore 'AppDelegate' settings, gave example ;) Nvm, it was just a misunderstanding. As for now i do moreover as you wrote, on B 'viewWillAppear' and 'viewDidDisappear' i swap settings, but it's not a good solution. Still looking for way to do it via '[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:]'. Thanks for suggestions.